# Identical Gridview in different div

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is that any way i can create **only one** gridview and display it in a few div?
Thanks.

Example:

```
<div id="divA">
//In divA, the GridViewA will bind with data source A and display in divA
</div>

<div id="divB">
//In divB, the GridViewA will bind with data source A and display in divB
</div>

<asp:GridView ID="GridViewA" runat="server" Width="100%" >
<Columns>       
<asp:BoundField></asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Datasource for both is different how can they be similar ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Should be the same data source

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using jQuery's clone() function. See example below.

```
$(function() 
{
    $('#<%= GridViewA.ClientID %>').clone().appendTo('#divA');
    $('#<%= GridViewA.ClientID %>').clone().appendTo('#divB');
});
```

If you do not want your original GridViewA to display, use following code.

```
$(function() 
{
    $('#<%= GridViewA.ClientID %>').clone().appendTo('#divA');
    $('#<%= GridViewA.ClientID %>').appendTo('#divB');
});
```

And if you are not using jQuery, following is a simple JavaScript solution.

```
<script>
    function onLoad() 
    {
        document.getElementById('divA').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%= GridViewA.ClientID %>').outerHTML;
        document.getElementById('divB').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%= GridViewA.ClientID %>').outerHTML;
    }
</script>
<body onload="onLoad();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="divA"></div>
        <div id="divB"></div>       

        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewA" runat="server"></asp:GridView>     
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```